# Plotting regressions from slope and intercept (lattice or ggplot2)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

I have a microarray dataset on which I performed a `limma` `lmFit()` test. If you haven't heard of it before, it's a powerful linear model package that tests differential gene expressions for >20k genes. You can extract the slope and intercept from the model for each one of these genes.

**My problem is: given a table of slope and intercept values, how do I match a plot (I don't mind either `ggplot2`'s `geom_abline`, `lattice`'s `panel.abline`, or an alternative if necessary) with its corresponding slope and intercept?**

My table (call it "slopeInt") has intercept as column 1 and slope as column 2, and has row names that correspond to the name of the gene. Their names look like this:

```
"202586_at"   "202769_at"   "203201_at"   "214970_s_at" "219155_at"
```

These names match my gene names in another table ("Data") containing some details about my samples (I have 24 samples with different IDs and Time/Treatment combination) and the gene expression values.

It's in the long format with the gene names (as above) repeating every 24 rows (different expression levels for same gene, for each one of my samples):

```
ID    Time  Treatment  Gene_name    Gene_exp
...   ...   ...        ...          ...
```

I have overall eight genes I'm interested to plot, and the names in my `Data$Gene_name` match the row names of my `slopeInt` table. I can also merge the two tables together, that's not a problem. But I tried the following two approaches to give me graphs with graphs for every one of my genes with the appropriate regression, to no avail:

Using `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Time, y = Gene_exp, group = Time, color = Treatment)) +
facet_wrap(~ Gene_name, scales = "free_x") +
geom_point() +
geom_abline(intercept = Intercept, slope = Time), data = slopeInt) +
theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())`
```

And also using `Lattice`:

```
xyplot(Gene_exp ~ Time| Gene_name, Data, 
   jitter.data = T,
   panel = function(...){
     panel.xyplot(...)
     panel.abline(a = slopeInt[,1], b = slopeInt[,2])},
   layout = c(4, 2))
```

I've tried multiple other methods in the actual `geom_abline()` and `panel.abline()` arguments, including some for loops, but I am not experienced in R and I cannot get it to work.. I can also have the data file in a wide format (separate columns for each gene).

Any help and further directions will be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is some code for a reproducible example:

```
Data <- data.frame(
 ID = rep(1:24, 8),
 Time = (rep(rep(c(1, 2, 4, 24), each = 3), 8)),
 Treatment = rep(rep(c("control", "smoking"), each = 12), 8),
 Gene_name = rep(c("202586_at", "202769_at", "203201_at", "214970_s_at",
   "219155_at", "220165_at", "224483_s_at", "227559_at"), each = 24),
 Gene_exp = rnorm(192))

slopeInt <- data.frame(
 Intercept = rnorm(8),
 Slope = rnorm(8))


row.names(slopeInt) <- c("202586_at", "202769_at", "203201_at",
"214970_s_at", "219155_at", "220165_at", "224483_s_at", "227559_at")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With lattice, this should work

```
xyplot(Gene_exp ~ Time| Gene_name, Data, slopeInt=slopeInt,
   jitter.data = T,
   panel = function(..., slopeInt){
     panel.xyplot(...)
     grp <- trellis.last.object()$condlevels[[1]][which.packet()]
     panel.abline(a = slopeInt[grp,1], b = slopeInt[grp,2])
   },
   layout = c(4, 2)
)
```

using `set.seed(15)` before generating the sample data results in the following plot

[image]

The "trick" here is to use `trellis.last.object()$condlevels` to determine which conditioning block we are currently in. Then we use that information to extract the right slope information from the additional data we now pass in via a parameter. I thought there was a more elegant way to determine the current values of the conditioning variables but if there is I cannot remember it at this time.

Comment: Thank you so much! It has definitely helped in that it plots one line per plot, and that it's in lattice. But the regression does not match my Data$Gene_name column so the regression lines are misplaced within each plot. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: They seem to match up for me with with the test data. Do you see a specific case where the lines don't match up here? If it works with the sample data, you may want to take time to look at how your real data is different. We can only help if there is a clear, reproducible problem.

Comment: Hi MrFlick, it ended up working for me. The problem was in the way the coef() function extracts the limma coefficients; it somehow jumbled up the results. Thanks again, I'd upvote if I could

Answer (score 1):

If you specify `Gene_name` as a column in `slopeInt`, then it works [as I understand you want it to]. Note also a few other changes to the ggplot call.

```
slopeInt$Gene_name <- rownames(slopeInt)
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Time, y = Gene_exp, color = Treatment)) +
   facet_wrap(~ Gene_name, scales = "free_x") +
   geom_point() +
   geom_abline(aes(intercept = Intercept, slope = Slope), data = slopeInt) +
   theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())
```

Comment: I see the changes but where does your call end up using the new column that you have made? I tried implementing this graph but it gives me all regression lines on each one of the 8 plots... Can it be so that only the appropriate regression line is showing? Cheers